# javax.naming.NameNotFoundException JBoss 4.3 to JBoss 7

Tags: java, maven, jboss

I'm trying to migrate a project from JBoss 4.3 to JBoss 7
while deploying I'm getting the below error:

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: a.b.c -- service jboss.naming.context.java."a.b.c"
```

In JBoss 4.3 the this was defined in a XML file as below:

```
<jndi:binding name="a.b.c">
                <jndi:value type="java.lang.String">http://localhost:8080/proj.abc.app/ABCServiceEndpoint?wsdl</jndi:value>
                </jndi:binding>
```

Can anyone advice on how to configure this for JBoss 7?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the [JNDI Reference of JBoss AS 7.1](https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/AS71/JNDI+Reference).

I would say, your migrated XML configuration is:

```
<subsystem xmlns="urn:jboss:domain:naming:1.1" >
    <bindings>
        <simple name="java:global/a.b.c" value="http://localhost:8080/proj.abc.app/ABCServiceEndpoint?wsdl" type="java.lang.String" />
    </bindings>
</subsystem>
```